# To whom do I return stolen cards?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

With [Molten Primordial](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMolten%20Primordial%5d) I've taken a creature from opponent 2, which had been previously taken from and is owned by opponent 1. When I lose control of it at end of turn to which opponent does it go?

Comment: That depends on exactly how player 2 got control of that creature. Please clarify in your question.

Comment: It was with Empress Galina. Mind explaining how a different card would result in a difference?

Comment: @Hackworth A variation like that can simply be addressed in an answer. A question like this doesn't need to be narrowed that much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Control-changing effects work in a system of layers, with the latest one being active. When the currently active effect expires, the previous effect takes over. In your case, where player 2 gained control via [Empress Galina](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEmpress%20Galina%5d), the creature would return to player 2.**

The rules governing the interaction of continuous effects are, in part, as follows:

> 613. Interaction of Continuous Effects
>
> 613.1. The values of an object’s characteristics are determined by starting with the actual object. For a card, that means the values of the characteristics printed on that card. For a token or a copy of a spell or card, that means the values of the characteristics defined by the effect that created it. Then all applicable continuous effects are applied in a series of layers in the following order:
>
> 613.1b Layer 2: Control-changing effects are applied.
>
> 613.2. Within layers 1–6, apply effects from characteristic-defining abilities first (see rule 604.3), then all other effects in timestamp order (see rule 613.6). [..]
>
> 613.6. Within a layer or sublayer, determining which order effects are applied in is usually done using a timestamp system. An effect with an earlier timestamp is applied before an effect with a later timestamp.

The timestamp reflects the order in which an object entered the battlefield or the ability that created the effect resolved. The effect of your Molten Primordial would have the latest timestamp, as far as control-changing effects on the creature are concerned. That's why it is applied last and overrides all other control-changing effects.

That means that previous control-changing effects are still on that creature if they didn't expire yet, they are just all overridden by the latest one. That means that if player 2's control-changing effect is still active by the time the turn and Molten Primordial's effect ends, player 2's effect takes over and the creature switches to player 2's control. If player 2's control-changing effect also has ended by that time, player 1 gets control back, because that's the default.

Answer (score 3):

In most cases, the creature goes back to whichever player controlled it before you, but that can change depending on how that player gained control of the creature.

The key idea to understanding how this works is that control-changing effects in Magic are continuous effects. If two players have an effect that lets them take control of the same creature, then both exist at the same time, and whichever was created later determines which player ends up controlling the creature. These effects can also have durations, including the one on Molten Primordial, which lasts "until end of turn". When it ends, you just look at what other control change effects still exist, if any, and use them to determine which player ends up controlling the creature. In the scenario you describe, there are two main possibilities:

1. Opponent 2's control change effect still exists after the Molten Primordial's effect ends. This includes effects that last forever, like from [Empress Galina](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEmpress%20Galina%5d). In this case, control goes back to opponent 2.
2. Opponent 2's control change effect ends at the same time as or before the Molten Primordial's effect ends. This would generally apply if they had used their own effect that lasts until end of turn, like [Word of Seizing](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWord%20of%20Seizing%5d). In that case, there would be no remaining control change effects, so control would go back to opponent 1.